# Using pointers and resourcestring

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to show the content of an array of constants attached to a Resourcestring; but it doesn't work properly (Showmessage should show 'Primavera') but you get a blank message and exception when you finish the application. The example code works well in Lazurus, for example. I'm missing something....

```
unit U_Translate;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

Resourcestring

  RS1 = 'Primavera'; RS2 = 'Verano'; RS3 = 'Otoño'; RS4 = 'Invierno';

Const
 CEstacion: Array [1..4] of ^String = (@RS1,@RS2,@RS3,@RS4);

var Form1: TForm1;

implementation
$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage (CEstacion[1]^);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why not declare: `CEstacion: array[1..4] of string = (RS1,RS2,RS3,RS4);` and display with: `ShowMessage(CEstacion[1])`

Comment: @LURD: But will those array elements be (localizable) resource strings then?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I guess you are right. If I remember correct, in a unicode Delphi version, the resourcestrings are of the `WideString` type.  Perhaps changing the type to `^WideString` may help.

Comment: No, changing to `^WideString` had no effect.

Comment: Try turning ON the Safe Pointer Type {$T+} and see if you are using a compatible pointer type in your array.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, Peter Below says that the compiler treats the resourcestrings in a special way during unit initialization to resolve the references, and that the proposal in my first comment may actually work.  In my test, it compiles and writes the correct text, but I have no time to test if the localization will pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using resourcestrings in a const array the values of the array are being initialized during unit initialization. At that point they are being loaded from the resources of the binary. The reason of them being empty can only mean you have some translation resource where you did not translate those resource strings yet.

Using resource strings that way also means that you you cannot just change the language at runtime and have the values being changed (unless you explicitly reinitialize the array but that requires quite some explicit low level code - see `System._InitResStrings`)

Another way would be to use an array of PResStringRec like this:

```
const
  CEstacion: array [1..4] of PResStringRec = (@RS1,@RS2,@RS3,@RS4);
```

and then call it like this (when using resourcestrings the compiler usually inserts the call to LoadResString for you)

```
ShowMessage(LoadResString(CEstacion[1]));
```

What we would need as language extension would be to be able to declare `array of resourcestring` which the compiler would translate to an array of `PResStringRec` and insert the `LoadResString` calls just like for normal resourcestrings.

Comment: Thank you @LURD;@AndreasRejbrand; @HeartWare; and above all @StefanGlienke for sharing a clear solution on this issue here. Always learning every day.

Comment: (and if you use dxgettext, it is _() instead of LoadResString)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is necessary to use pointers in FreePascal/Lazarus, but there is no need to do that in Delphi:

```
resourcestring
  RS1 = 'Primavera'; 
  RS2 = 'Verano'; 
  RS3 = 'Otoño'; 
  RS4 = 'Invierno';

const
  CEstacion: array[1..4] of string = (RS1, RS2, RS3, RS4);

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(CEstacion[1]);
end;
```

That works fine. Now the array will not be modified once the application is running, but it can be localized for other languages when the app is not running and the different names will be used. Use the usual tools.

Comment: The idea of proposing the use of an array with pointers to a resourcestring has been to be able to implement the update of the resourcestring array at runtime. In that case using the usual way, at least through the well-known Gnugettext library does not seem to work.

Comment: @Silver - the *idea* is missing in the question.

Comment: @Silver: AFAIK, you can't simply change resourcestrings at runtime. And ISTM that GnuGetText doesn't do that either. It changes variables.

Comment: Dear @RudyVelthuis, thanks for answering and excuse my English. Regarding resourcestring, they can get a different value at runtime, invoking a language change through Gnugettext. Then assigning the resourcestring to an array using pointers as shown by Stefan Glienke can work with the associated arrays as well.

Comment: @Silver: does Gnugettext change Windows resources embedded in the executable as generated by resourcestring, or does it simply replace one string for another (the first string being the ID -- or key--, the second the msg -- or value), using a function that gets strings from a .po or .mo file? AFAICT, it does the latter. That is not the same as resourcestring.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I don't know if I understand your question....The only thing I could add is to call the ResourceString identifier directly and the output is the string translated properly, after invoking UseLanguage('xx'); in Gnugettext: In the example of this thread, making a Showmessage (RS1); and without using any support function like gettext or _(); we already get different RS1 outputs, the constant declared as ResourceString. So based on this, does RS1 really change at runtime?

Comment: @Silver: I don't know your code, so I can hardly comment on it. Would be cool if you could post a working example to a code site and post a link to it here. Which Gnugettext implementation for Delphi are you using?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, updated the entry; This is the header of the GnuGettext version used and compiled with Tokyo 10.2; https://sourceforge.net/p/dxgettext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/dxgettext/sample/gnugettext.pas - A full example can be found with ResourceString as well.

Comment: Rudy: it gets the strings from a mo file(which is "compiled po). However it hooks into the resourcestring system, so those are autotranslated as long as they are not in a structured constant.  You also need to add a function to all forms to translate form resources.   Language can be swapped runtime, but that only works if you can force the framework to reget all strings, which is often not practical. Note that Lazarus uses a different own gettext.

Comment: @Marco: thanks. That was the info I was looking for.